# Fluent NHibernate Automappings generating 2 foreign keys for 1 relationship

Tags: c#, fluent-nhibernate, automapping

I have this setup (condensed for brevity)

```
Class Employee
    virtual IList<ChecklistItem> HasInitialed { get; private set; }

Class ChecklistItem
    virtual Employee InitialedBy { get; set; }
```

When this is generated I get these tables

```
Employee
    Id

ChecklistItem
    Id
    InitialedBy_id <----
    Employee_id <----
```

The ChecklistItem has 2 foreign keys for Employee, I'm assuming Employee_id to map ChecklistItem.Employee and InitialedBy_id to map ChecklistItem.InitialedBy. How can I tell NHibernate that this is the same bidirectional relationship and only requires 1 foreign key?

I'm kind of new to NHibernate in general, but this seems like it should be pretty standard.

This is what I've come up with when I'm configuring my database to generate the right schema, is it right?

```
.Override<Employee>(map => map
    .HasMany<ChecklistItem>(x => x.HasInitialed)
    .KeyColumn("InitialedBy_id"))
```

If that is right, is there a way to choose KeyColumn based on the ChecklistItem's property name (a lambda)?

Answer (score 0):

as a convention for all hasmanies

```
class HasManyConvention : IHasManyConvention
{
    public void Apply(IOneToManyCollectionInstance instance)
    {
        instance.Key.Column(((ICollectionInspector)instance).Name + "_id");
    }
}
```

or only for this

```
class HasManyConvention : IHasManyConvention, IHasManyConventionAcceptance
{
    public void Accept(IAcceptanceCriteria<IOneToManyCollectionInspector> criteria)
    {
        criteria.Expect(x => x.Name == "HasInitialed"); // and/or entity type
    }

    public void Apply(IOneToManyCollectionInstance instance)
    {
        instance.Key.Column(((ICollectionInspector)instance).Name + "_id");
    }
}
```

convention for Manytoone/References

```
class ReferenceConvention : IReferenceConvention
{
    public void Apply(IManyToOneInstance instance)
    {
        instance.Column(instance.Name + "_id");
    }
}
```

Comment: This changes Employee_id to HasInitialed_id, but it still generates another key

Comment: Can I access the 'Many' side of the relationship here?